# remove object from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a familytree looking like this:

```
{

    "children": [{
        "name": "bob",
        "children": [{
            "name": "sam",
            "children": [{
                "name": "mike",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "elias",
                    "children": []
                }, {
                    "name": "rodriguez",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

The main `"children"` is an array containing nested child-arrays.
How can I remove an object from an array like this?
Lets say I want to remove the object with the name "sam", that should leave me with the following:

```
{
    "children": [{
        "name": "bob",
        "children": []
    }]
}
```

Its the nesting that trips me up and i do not understand how to start.

Any help or directions to a tutorial that deals with similar issues are appreciated.

Comment: Assuming there are many sams, do you want to remove all of them?

Comment: Based on the wording of his question, it's ambiguous - but I'd say your solution assumed the best possible interpretation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is a good tool to work with trees.

```js
var tree = {

    "children": [{
        "name": "bob",
        "children": [{
            "name": "sam",
            "children": [{
                "name": "mike",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "elias",
                    "children": []
                }, {
                    "name": "rodriguez",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

function removeFromTree(parent, childNameToRemove){
  parent.children = parent.children
      .filter(function(child){ return child.name !== childNameToRemove})
      .map(function(child){ return removeFromTree(child, childNameToRemove)});
  return parent;
}
tree = removeFromTree(tree, 'elias')         
console.log(tree);
document.write(JSON.stringify(tree));
```

This tutorial looks interesting (section "Binary Trees" and "Graphs"). I think it could help to implement your requirements: https://www.syncano.io/blog/data-structures-in-javascript/

Comment: Should `{"name":"rodriguez","children":[]}` be removed from tree ?

Comment: Ah, `{"name":"rodriguez","children":[]}` is a sibling of `"elias"`

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you all who helped.

Answer (score 4):

This is a proposal which iterates over the objects and uses backtracking for deleting the wanted node with the given name.

This solution keeps the original object and uses short circuit to prevent more than necessaray iterations.

It uses recusion as well.

```js
function deleteFromTree(o, name) {
    function getNode(a, i) {
        if (a.name === name) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(getNode)) {
            if (~index) {
                a.children.splice(index, 1);
                index = -1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index = -1;
    [o].some(getNode);
}

var tree = { "children": [{ "name": "bob", "children": [{ "name": "sam", "children": [{ "name": "mike", "children": [{ "name": "elias", "children": [] }, { "name": "rodriguez", "children": [] }] }] }] }] };

deleteFromTree(tree, 'sam');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

> The main "children" is an array containing nested child-arrays. How
>   can I remove an object from an array like this? Lets say I want to
>   remove the object with the name "sam", that should leave me with the
>   following:
>
> ```
> {
>     "children": [{
>         "name": "bob",
>         "children": []
>     }]
> }
> ```

You can utilize [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) `replacer` parameter to remove properties from returned `JSON` string

> **replacer** Optional
>  A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that
>   serve as a whitelist for selecting the properties of the value object
>   to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not
>   provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting
>   JSON string.
>
> **The replacer parameter**
>
> The replacer parameter can be either a function or an array. As a
>   function, it takes two parameters, the key and the value being
>   stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the
>   replacer's this parameter. Initially it gets called with an empty key
>   representing the object being stringified, and it then gets called for
>   each property on the object or array being stringified. It should
>   return the value that should be added to the JSON string, as follows:
>
> - If you return a `Number`, the string corresponding to that number is    used as the value for the property when added to the JSON
>     string.
> - If you return a `String`, that string is used as the property's value    when adding it to the JSON string.
> - If you return a `Boolean`,"true" or "false" is used as the property's value, as appropriate,    when adding it to the JSON
>     string.
> - If you return any other    object, the object is recursively stringified into the JSON string,    calling the replacer function on
>     each property, unless the object is    a function, in which case
>     nothing is added to the JSON string.
> - If you return undefined, the property is not included in the output JSON    string.
>
>   Note: You cannot use the replacer function to remove values from an
>     array. If you return undefined or a function then null is used
>     instead.

---

```
var prop = "name";
var value = "sam";
var res = JSON.stringify(data, function re(a, obj) {;
     return obj[prop] === value ? null : obj
  }, 2);

console.log(res, JSON.parse(res));
```

```js
var data = {
  "children": [{
    "name": "bob",
    "children": [{
      "name": "sam",
      "children": [{
        "name": "mike",
        "children": [{
          "name": "elias",
          "children": []
        }, {
          "name": "rodriguez",
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var prop = "name";
var value = "sam";
var res = JSON.stringify(data, function re(a, obj) {;
     return obj[prop] === value ? null : obj
  }, 2);

console.log(res, JSON.parse(res));

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = res;
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: i do not see anything (ie11)

Comment: @NinaScholz Interesting. Have not tried ie browser in some time. Any errors logged at `console` ? Tried at firefox , chrome / chromium browser ? What is logged at `console.log(b, b[curr[prop]])` within `for` loop ?

Comment: `var curr = Object.keys(b);` *Object.keys: Das Argument ist kein Objekt* translates to *'argument is no object'*.

Comment: Tried adjusting condition to `if (b && typeof b === "object")` ? What is `b` at error ?

Comment: @NinaScholz Well, this makes the process simpler for us, yes ? See updated post

Comment: @NinaScholz If `b` is `"bob"` at ie11, what does `return b === n ? null : n` produce ?

Comment: @NinaScholz See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3 at 3. "If `ReplacerFunction` is not **undefined**, then"

Comment: @NinaScholz Curious about ie11 implementation of specification; what is result of `return b === n || b["name"] === n ? null : b`  ?

Comment: sorry, had to sleep. but now it works perfectly. btw tricky idea to use a build in recursive iterator.

Comment: @NinaScholz _"sorry, had to sleep."_ Impossible with so much to discover ! _"but now it works perfectly."_ Was wondering if ie implementation was different.

Comment: @NinaScholz  Could be entirely incorrect, though when trying destructuring had the sense the process was somewhat similar to `JSON.stringify` `replacer`; still exploring option of passing string to `replacer`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\{"name":"sam".*(?=\]\}\]\})/` to match property having property `"name"` with value `"sam"` remove remainder of string until `]}]}` is portion of string with `String.prototype.replace()`

```
var res = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(data)
  .replace(JSON.stringify(data).match(/\{"name":"sam".*(?=\]\}\]\})/)[0]
  , ""
  , ["children"])
);
```

```js
var data = {

  "children": [{
    "name": "bob",
    "children": [{
      "name": "sam",
      "children": [{
        "name": "mike",
        "children": [{
          "name": "elias",
          "children": []
        }, {
          "name": "rodriguez",
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

var res = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(data)
  .replace(JSON.stringify(data).match(/\{"name":"sam".*(?=\]\}\]\})/)[0]
  , ""
  , ["children"])
);

console.log(data)

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: This is exactly how not to do that.

Comment: @georg Yes, aware of that, though fun to try

Comment: @georg The `RegExp` at `(?=\]\}\]\})` could certainly be improved. Could also substitute `JSON.stringify()`s function for `RegExp` to adjust resulting string