# Array filter returns strange results

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, hasownproperty

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232576/how-to-filter-object-using-array-prototype-filter) question, i wanted to try out this

```
var arr = [0,1,2,true,4,{"abc":123},6,7,{"def":456},9,[10]];
arr.filter(Object.hasOwnProperty,"abc");//outputs [0, 1, 2]
arr.filter(Object.hasOwnProperty,"2222222") //[0, 1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Does anyone knows why filter return these values? [Spec of filter](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.filter) and [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) also doesn't clearly tell how second argument of filter is used.

Comment: The spec says `Array.prototype.filter ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )` right in the header and *"If a `thisArg` parameter is provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of `callbackfn`."* on paragraph later - How could it be any more clear than that?

Comment: @Tomalak well it wasn't clear to me, pardon my ignorance. Otherwise why would I ask a question? Saying that `it will be used as this value for each invocation` is not exaclty `2+2=4`.

Comment: It says "as **the** `this` value for each invocation", and not having encountered `this` before in JS is strangely at odds with the ability to write lines like `arr.filter(Object.hasOwnProperty,"2222222")`. (BTW, I didn't downvote, if you think that.)

Comment: @Tomalak I am pretty sure I have encountered `this` before in JS :) But I wasn't sure about how it is being used. Please check the discussion in below answer to understand why it may not be that straightforward. I am not worried about downvotes as much as long as I know how I can improve on my post.

Comment: @Tomalak Perhaps you can provide insight at linked Question ? Please illuminate

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's too late, but I felt compelled to add an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument to the `Array.prototype.filter` is the value that will be set as `this` to the function that is passed as a first argument.

So your code ends up to be something like:

```
arr.filter(function(v, i, a) {
    return Object.hasOwnProperty.call("222", v, i, a);
});
```

So it basically checks if the `"222"` string has the properties you enumerate in the array.

From that it becomes clear why properties `0`, `1` and `2` are found - since those are the indexes of the characters in the `"222"` string, and, say, `9` or `{"abc":123}` are not - since `"222"` string does not have such a properties.

It is the same story with the longer string, which also includes properties `4` and `6` just because it's longer.

Some examples:

```
Object.hasOwnProperty.call("222", 1); // true, because `"222"[1]` is there
Object.hasOwnProperty.call("222", 'foo'); // false, because `"222"['foo']` is not there
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not `"222"[1]` but `new String("222")[1]` - autoboxing.

Comment: @georg `"222"[1]` is an expression that involves auto boxing under the hood, so I don't see a point.

Comment: @zerkms `[1,2]` was returned here  as `n` at `var arr = [0,1,2,true,4,{"abc":123},6,7,{"def":456},9,[10]];var n = arr.filter(Object.hasOwnProperty, "abc");` . If `0` is replaced with `7` , `[2]` is returned. Why is `[1,2]` returned where `0` is at index `0` , but `[2]` returned where `7` is at index `0` ?

Comment: @guest271314 okay, and that complies with what I explained, doesn't it?

Comment: @zerkms Your Answer provides _"From that it becomes clear why properties 0, 1 and 2 are found"_ , though only `[1,2]` are returned , not `0` . Is `0` converted to `false` at `.hasOwnProperty` call ? Not certain why substituting `7` for `0` would return `[2]` ?

Comment: I just tried your code and `[0, 1, 2]` are returned as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/q1w3csj5/

Comment: @zerkms Actually, the way that you described the process is helpful. How do we get , believe, `v` to the position of `"222"` at `return Object.hasOwnProperty.call("222", v, i, a);` ? e.g., if `"222"` is the property of the object we want to be returned at `.filter()` ?

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: @zerkms Not sure why `n` was delivering `[1,2]` at `console` ?

Comment: @zerkms  _"I'm not getting what you mean"_ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232576/how-to-filter-object-using-array-prototype-filter

Comment: @zerkms Maybe it was the `7` that was returning `[1, 2]` earlier https://jsfiddle.net/q1w3csj5/1/. Though fairly certain at some point at `console` `[1,2]` was returned . Will try again at `console`

Comment: @guest271314 maybe because I inserted 0 in the `arr` (first index) in my question.

Comment: @guest271314 because "abc" doesn't have 7th index.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Why is only `[1,2]` returned when result of `.filter()` is assigned to a variable ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The array has different items; compare https://jsfiddle.net/q1w3csj5/2/ . Try with first array at linked Question

Comment: @guest271314 yes, and only first two of them have the indexes less than or equal to 2. Other items in array are values greater than 2. `"abc".length === 3`

Comment: @gurvinder372 At least we can be fairly certain the value is reaching `.hasOwnProperty`; now, how to return the object that has property `"abc"`, and not the index

Comment: @guest271314 IMHO we need to explore another method than `hasOwnProperty` :)

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes, of course; any approach involving the least methods , function calls that can be consolidated to a single line. Perhaps even a method other than `.filter()`; some form of `JSON.stringify()` `replacer` "string" option to pass object properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228492/remove-object-from-nested-array coupled with `destructuring`

Answer (score 4):

It's crystal clear from the spec

> `Array.prototype.filter ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )`,
>
> If a`thisArg` parameter is provided, it will be used as the `this` value
>   for each invocation of `callbackfn`.

So:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,true,4,{"abc":123},6,7,{"def":456},9,[10]];
arr.filter(Object.hasOwnProperty,"2222222");
```

translates to these calls, in sequence

```
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(0);             // true     -> 0
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(1);             // true     -> 1
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(2);             // true     -> 2
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(true);          // false    -> 
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(4);             // true     -> 4
"2222222".hasOwnProperty({"abc":123});   // false    -> 
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(6);             // true     -> 6
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(7);             // false    -> 
"2222222".hasOwnProperty({"def":456});   // false    -> 
"2222222".hasOwnProperty(9);             // false    -> 
"2222222".hasOwnProperty([10]);          // false    -> 
                                         // filter() => [0,1,2,4,6]
```

The lines where it says `true` are because strings can be indexed into like arrays, so a string with two characters has the indexes `0` and `1` as own properties.

Comment: How do we re-arrange or otherwise persuade `{"abc":123}.hasOwnProperty("abc");` ? Though in correct form to return `{"abc":123}` from `.filter()` ?

Comment: @guest271314 you mean `({"abc":123}).hasOwnProperty("abc")` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes. Arrange for syntax to be correct, and for `.hasOwnProperty` to recognize `{"abc":123}` as the object that it is applying property check at